# how to load all control variable names and then edit their properties

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to load all the control variables for and example 
Button1
Button2 
Button3

And then Edit their properties like

```
Button1.settext() ;
```

Please tell me is their a way to do this .

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider adding some more context to your question, for example what you tried and what errors are you getting...

Comment: I want to create a application which can change the colors or icons of some controls . like Jlabels .
and i have alot of controls so its hard for me to write all variable names and then set properties .

Comment: i want a code to load all controls available in my application and then to change properties

Comment: What do you mean by "control variables"? Of course, when you are writing a GUI application; and that application contains buttons, labels, fields, etc - then all of these "controls" are objects and have methods to change their properties. You should provide the code you created so far and point out where your problems are.

Comment: Im a beginner so please forgive for lack of my knowledge ,  okay if i say it in a easy way . I want to edit all jlabels at once .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all those labels in the same frame, you can try the following:

```
Arrays.asList(myframe.getComponents()).forEach((c) -> {
    if( c instanceof JLabel) {
        JLabel l = (JLabel)c;
        //do whatever you'd like to do with your label here...
    }
});
```